# How to check two LatLng values using if condition in google map api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, if-statement

I have developed a map with routes using DirectionsRenderer ... i need the destination marker to be bounced if origin and destination are at same place ... but when i check whether the two LatLng values are same using IF, the program does not execute the IF statement ... the destination marker is not getting bounced.. my coding is

```
        var myOptions = 
    {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(default_latitude,default_longitude),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
    var latlng1=new google.maps.LatLng(glat,glon);
    var latlng2=new google.maps.LatLng(hlat,hlon);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
            icon: "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/B/67BF4B/000000/00902C/", 
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(glat,glon),
            map: map
        });


    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                icon: " http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/A/67BF4B/000000/00902C/", 
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(hlat,hlon),
                map: map

            });  

    //THIS IF STATEMENT IS NOT WORKING ... WHAT CAN I USE INSTEAD OF THIS 
        if(latlng1==latlng2)
            marker1.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE); 



    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("panel"));
    var request = {
      origin: latlng1,
      destination:latlng2,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Try equals method in LatLng to compare 2 location](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

change  `if(latlng1==latlng2)` to  `if(latlng1.equals(latlng2))`

Comment: But see, if you want to check near by location you can use @geocodezip's solution

Comment: ya sure friend ... tats obviously a fine tuned solution ... will use geocodezip's code for very minute map api's in future ... thanks for both of ur support

Answer (score 6):

To determine if 2 google.maps.LatLng objects are the same location, pick a distance (like 0.1 meters), calculate the distance between them, if it is less than the threshold, assume they are the same place.  Comparing objects will only return true if they are the same identical object.  Comparing 2 floating point numbers is problematic, and comparing two pairs of floating point objects is even more so.

```
var SameThreshold = 0.1;
if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng1,latlng2) < SameThreshold)
   marker1.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

Be sure to include the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries)

- [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance)
- [Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

Comment: urs is also working sir ... but Krisl code is a simpler one ... but thanks for ur support ... expect the same for my future questions too ...

Comment: +1 @geocodezip for better solution in case to check nearby location. Thank you